# how to implement iter_size like caffe in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow. My gpu memory is not enough, so I want to average the gradients of 4 iterations to update variable.

How to do this in tensorflow?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, at first google it, try yourself then if you got stuck, then come here and add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: In tensorflow, doing back-propagation with built-in optimizers are much simpler in programming. Considering the memory issue, would you try a smaller batch size and do back-propagation once in every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I think [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.12/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) might be useful for your problem. It compute N batches with N GPUs and then do the back propagation once. What you need to do is modify the Line 165-166. Run 'compute_gradients()' 'iter_size' times and run 'average_gradients()' once.

Comment: first provide an answer and then examples.

Comment: Link only answers are not well accepted on this forum.  Show the code and then reference the link.

Comment: yes. Tensorflow provides some official examples. But the code is a bit trivial and not so convenient to write multi-gpu parallel programs.